# express regex routing

Tags: node.js, regex, express, routes

I'm trying to setup a regex for handling routes through Express.

My get input have this form :

```
 - site/?...
 - site/?P1=V1....
 - site/?P1=V1&P2=V2....
```

I tried :

```
^(\/)(\\?)     ===> catch site/?
^(\/)(\\?)(P)  ===> didn't catch site/?P
```

I use :

- npm version : 5.0.3
- express : ^4.15.3

im still learning, so if it shouldn't work like this, correct me please :)
and thanks for the help, peace :)

Comment: Why do you need to specify query params in route?